# Open .sql extensions in ssms 2008 r2 rather than ssms 2012

Tags: ssms

I want to open .sql extensions automatically in ssms 2008 r2 rather than ssms 2012 for reasons I won't bore you with. On Windows 7. It can't be done through the normal file types and default programs dialogues as it seems just to associate with the generic program rather than the version, so presumably I need to do something in the registry. Can anyone advise?

Many thanks,

James

Comment: Right click on sql file, OpenWith, Choose default program, check uthis program for all sql files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Giorgi, but that didn't work for me. Maybe if I'd rebooted it might have done, but I didn't think we needed to do that these days.

Answer:
Download a 3rd party File Type Manager (Nirsoft FileTypesMan worked for me) and change the entries to the following:

Associate the following program (SSMS 2008 R2) with the file type:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"

Associate the following with the Open action:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe" /dde "%1"

In the DDE details for the Open action, add the following:
Message:     Open("%1")
Application: sqlwb.9.0
Ifexec:      {leave this blank}
Topic:       system